# How to ping an IP address from an Android device?

Tags: android, ping

Is there a way to ping an IP address from an Android device?

Is there a Android built-in application or am I to download an app for my task?

Comment: just pinging or other job??

Comment: just pinging, windows has cmd (command prompt), what about android?

Comment: @HPM: Are you aware of [android.se]?

Comment: my question closed, there are lots of stack sites, please tell me where I should ask my question?

Comment: I would recommend [PingTools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ua.com.streamsoft.pingtools&hl=en).

Comment: Related: [How to ping (some resource) on (some network) on an Android phone or emulator?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/8995/33031) (Android SE)

Comment: Android is just not linuxy enough. Gosh darnit, an OS that doesn't natively carry an accessible shell to perform even a simple ping. Dang it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using [connectbot](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/) - ([google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot&hl=en)), you can access a local shell and use the `ping` command. Start it up, select "local" from the list, leave Nickname as it is, and select OK with the keyboard.

[image]

Comment: How would you access a local shell that way? More details would be nice!

Comment: connectbot is a terminal emulator. You can use it allows you to open a remote terminal via SSH or Telnet, but you can also open a local terminal. You just have to choose "local" from the list, put nothing in the "Nickname" part and validate (OK) with the keyboard.

Comment: So there is no built in command prompt for Android, am I right?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a screenshot and editing in the information in the comment. I'm afraid I'm using a connectbot fork called VX Connectbot, but this should be identical to the standard version.

Comment: I've also added a google play link to connectbot. It hasn't been updated in a while - while *changing* the link and the software is above and beyond what I am comfortable editing, [VX Connectbot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.vx.connectbot&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInNrLnZ4LmNvbm5lY3Rib3QiXQ..) is a newer fork, and probably a better choice.

Comment: If you have no *Local* entry, add a new host and select `local` as the protocol. I nicknamed mine *localhost*.